# GraphQL syntax to access file by relativepath

Tags: graphql, gatsby

GatsbyJS [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images/) give this example for accessing a file by relativepath with GraphQL:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    fileName: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/myimage.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 250) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

I just can't get this working and I don't know why. I've tried all kinds of different syntaxes but the query always returns null for filename. This is my most recent attempt in Graph**i**QL:

```
{
    fileName: file(relativePath: { eq: "./html.js" }) {
      id
    } 
}
```

What am I missing? How can I access a file by relative path?

Edit after reading the answer:

In my `gatsby-config.js` there are several paths set as queriable:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `images`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`
  }
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/content/posts/`,
    name: "posts"
  }
},
....
```

When I make a query for `pic.jpg` (instead of `images/pic.jpg`), how does Gatsby know I want `images/pic.jpg` instead of `posts/pic.jpg`? How is this uniquely defining a path?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `relativePath` field of a File node is relative to the directory you specified in `gatsby-source-filesystem`.

For example, say I have a directory structure like this:

```
root
  |--gatsby-config.js
  `--dirA
      |--fileA.md
      `--dirB
          |--fileB.md
          `--dirC
               `--fileC.md
```

And in my `gatsby-config.js`

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dirA`, <---- root/dirA
    name: `dir`,
  },
}
```

The files inside `dirA` will have the following `relativePath`:

```
File      |  relativePath
---------------------------------
fileA.md  |  'fileA.md'
---------------------------------
fileB.md  |  'dirB/fileB.md'
---------------------------------
fileC.md  |  'dirB/dirC/fileC.md'
```

I can query `fileC` like this:

```
query {
  fileName: file(relativePath: {
    eq: "dirB/dirC/fileC.md"
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

So in your case, you can point `gatsby-source-filesystem` to the parent directory of `html.js`, and it should be queriable.

---

## Get unique file

If I have the following structure:

```
root
  |--gatsby-config.js
  |--dirD
  |   `--index.md
  `--dirE
      `--index.md
```

And point `gatsby-source-filesystem` to both of them, now there're 2 File nodes with the same `relativePath` (`index.md`).

In this case, it's not safe to do the following query:

```
query {
  fileName: file(relativePath: {
    eq: "index.md"
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

Because it will return the first File node that satisfies the filter condition (I'm not sure how gatsby decides file orders, if someone knows please share!). It'll be safer to add some additional unique filters.

For example, when I set `gatsby-source-filesystem`, I can specify a `name` property. This `name` will be stored in the `sourceInstanceName` field on File nodes.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dirE`,
    name: `dirE`,
  },
},
```

I can query it like so:

```
{
  file(
    relativePath: {
      eq: "index.md"
    },
    sourceInstanceName: {
      eq: "dirE"
    }
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

I think the combination of `sourceInstanceName` and `relativePath` is enough to ensure the file is unique.

Alternatively, you can also query File node by its `absolutePath`. This'll guarantee the file is unique, though you still need to tell `gatsby-source-filesystem` where the file lives.

In case you want to see all files that has the same `relativePath`, this query will do:

```
query {
  allFile(filter: {
    relativePath: { eq: "index.md" }
  }) {
    edges {
      node { 
        id
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, again! This works, though I'm still wondering how is this uniquely defining a path? I edited OP to clarify what I mean by this question.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen Hi Atte! I've updated the answer to address the edited question. In short, if you only rely on `relativePath`, Gatsby won't know which file you want, and will just return the first one that it can find. You'd have to add additional filters to ensure the file is unique.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also query File node by its `absolutePath` field, in which case you won't need to pass in additional filters.

Comment: This is a seriously good answer requiring a comment, not just a vote. :-) This doesn't seem to be clearly stated on the [Gatsby `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin page](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/) or [its GItHub repo](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem). Thank you.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

What caught me out is that per [this issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14395) you need to restart `gatsby develop` for the GraphQL data to refresh (i.e. after you adjust the `relativePath`).

This can be resolved by:

- Starting Gatsby with `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true gatsby develop`
- Running `curl -X POST localhost:8000/__refresh` in a separate terminal each time you want to refresh the data